# How to remove ajax selected value from the dropdown

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-10

I have the following form field where after submit it will add a value as selected by ajax at the top which works fine.

```
        <form id="addCarForm">
            @csrf
            <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
            <select name="cars" id="cars">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Mercedes" />
            <!-- Reset button -->
            <button id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
        </form>
```

But the reset button does not remove the selected value. Here is the reset code

```
// Reset button click event listener
$("#resetBtn").on("click", function () {
    // Reset the value of the select element to an empty value
    $("#cars").val("");

    // Remove the option added via AJAX
    $("#cars option[data-ajax]").remove();
});
```

It creates as follows

```
<option value="null" selected="">null</option>
```

But it should remove as below but it does not do that

```
<option value="volvo" selected="">volvo</option>
```

I have tried as below

```
// Reset the value of the select element to an empty value
$("#cars").val('');

// Remove the selected attribute from all options
$("#cars option").prop("selected", false);
```

Also as below

```
// Reset the value of the select element to an empty value
$("#cars").val('');

// Get the option added via AJAX
var ajaxOption = $("#cars option[data-ajax]");

// Remove the option if it exists
if (ajaxOption.length > 0) {
    ajaxOption.remove();
}

// Re-append the default option with an empty value
$("#cars").prepend('<option value="" data-ajax="">Select a car</option>');
```

But did not work as well. I have used jquery-3.6.0 and laravel 10. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistakes. Here I have put reset within the form and with submit.

```
<form>
.....
<input type="submit" value="Add Mercedes" />       
<button id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
</form>
```

So when I submit it creates a selected . If I click reset button it will delete but at the same time selected  will come up again.

So it was solved as below

```
<form>
.....
<input type="submit" value="Add Mercedes" />       
</form>
<button id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
```

Reset function it works fine as below

```
// Reset button click event listener
$("#resetBtn").on("click", function () {
    $("#cars :selected").remove();
});
```